# Magento Modules Development Tutorials

Tags: module, development

I have good understanding of PHP (my strongs are JAVA and C, but php in very similar in many aspects) and I need to start learn how to code Magento modules.

I can only find tutorials for 1.7 or early, are these OK or do I need a tutorial for 1.9? Which tutorials or web courses you recommend?

cheers

Answer (score -1):

For the most part, 1.7 should be fine.  Earlier versions (pre 1.5) handled resources a bit differently and so the structure may be different.

[Alan Storm](http://alanstorm.com/category/magento) provides some excellent resources for extension development as well as using Magento's framework in general. This might be a good place to start.

In addition, I find looking at the core modules extremely edifying.  It will give you a good sense of code style and structure - you can start with a simpler one like Mage/Contacts or Mage/Review to get started.

Magento offers a good course called "Fundamentals of Magento Development" - for a while, these videos were free, but that is no longer the case (they also have a in-person course for $3850). The online version is a couple hundred bucks.